# Fancybox: How to get the lightbox's DOM element in event?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have multiple galleries and I need to know which DOM element the current slide is from in the `initLayout` function. Using `this` returns the Fancybox instance and I don't see any properties in that instance that reference the DOM element.

```
Fancybox.bind( '[data-fancybox^="gallery-"]', {
    on: {
        initLayout: function ( fancybox ) {
            // Get the gallery's DOM element here, e.g. <div data-fancybox="gallery-3"></div>
        },
    },
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter to the done event.

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox^="gallery-"]', {
  on: {
    done: function (fancybox, slide) {
      // Logs the DOM element and the `gallery-<number>` string.
      console.log(slide.triggerEl, slide.triggerEl.dataset.fancybox); 
    },
  },
});
```

You can swap "done" for "loading" if you want it to fire sooner.